# cakephp localhostにてDB接続

Tags: mysql, cakephp

今、cakephpでmysqlに入れたデータをlocalhostにて読み込みをしたいのですが、
なぜかコントローラが見つかりませんとエラー表示がでて先に進めません。

ファイル名: UsersController

Member->find('all',array(
            'order'=>array(
                'id'=>'desc'
                )));
        $this->set('mem',$datas);
    }
}


  
        Html->text($list['Member']['id']);?>
        Html->link($list['Member']['name']);?＞

ちなみにパスはlocalhost/Users/listです（サーバ名/コントローラ/メソッド名）
何回やってもNot foundになる為、パスが間違っていると思います。

恐れ入りますが、アドバイスお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

コントローラーのメソッド名を`list`で作成していませんか？
listはphpの予約語のためメソッド名に使用することはできません。

PHP: キーワードのリスト - Manual http://php.net/manual/ja/reserved.keywords.php

コントローラーのメソッド名を変更してください。

urlが`/users/list`でなければいけないのであれば、ルーティングを利用してURLとコントローラーメソッドの紐付けをしてください。

ルーティング http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/development/routing.html

また、このような予約語を間違って使用したなどのイージーミスを防ぐためにNetBeans, PHPStormなどのIDEを利用するようにしましょう。

Comment: 有難う御座います。予約語とは見逃していました。。。
仰る通り、NetBeansを使うことにします。
ちなみに、コントローラのメソッド名を変更させていただいたのですが、コントローラが見つかりませんと表示がでてしまいます。
パス名 localhost/GreenBox/Green/index
内訳：ホスト名/htdocs以下のファイルパス/コントローラ名/メソッド名

なにが原因か教えていただければ幸いです。。。

Comment: 今いじっていたら修正できました！